# How do you configure the top left and right buttons of a Wacom?

Tags: 16.04, wacom

I just bought a Intous Draw Wacom. I noticed it has two upper buttons:
[image]

I'm using Gimp and Inkscape and they don't seem to do anything.

Should I configure them somewhere in my Ubuntu?

(Note: I'm using Ubuntu 16, and the pen and the buttons of the pen work perfectly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to configure these buttons using xsetwacom. Please see the following for an explanation of the issue:

https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/wiki/Consumer-Tablet-ExpressKey-Mapping-Issue